# Pandas Soma Condicional

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Olá.
Tenho a seguinte situação

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['a','b','c','a','c','a','b','c'],'Value':[9.2,8.6,7.2,8.3,8.5,2.1,7.4,1.1]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['a','b','c']})
```

e gostaria de obter a seguinte resposta

```
in [0]: df2
out[0]: 
  Key  soma
0   a  19.6
1   b  16.0
2   c  16.8
```

A única forma que conheço é a seguinte:

```
for ind,row in df2.iterrows():
        df2.soma[ind] = df1.loc[df1.Key == row.Key, 'Value'].sum()
```

Porém demora uma enormidade de tempo que inviabiliza minha execução, por se tratar de uma quantidade muito grande de dados.

abç a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme a resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13257677/3134655), uma outra forma possível para obter a coluna soma é você eliminar o *looping*  e utilizar um *groupby* (agregação) para criar a nova coluna:

```
df2['soma'] = df1.groupby('Key')["Value"].transform(np.sum)
```

Após a execução:

```
In [35]: df2
Out[35]:
  Key  soma
0   a  19.6
1   b  16.0
2   c  16.8
```

Caso você não esteja utilizando a biblioteca *numpy* (recomendado), substitua o `np.sum` por `sum`.

Comment: Ok, mas não sei o porque não está funcionando para mim. É a mesma estrutura, porém com mais dados (3milhoes) e 70 classes. Talvez não comporte esse volume

Comment: @Mueladavc Na execução, aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Ou  demora da mesma forma que na pergunta?

Comment: Não aparece mensagem nenhuma, a forma que consegui foi utilizar esse comando e depois eliminar os valores duplicados das 'Keys', já foi uma melhora substancial. Mas dessa forma como está ai, com esse dataframe de exemplo funciona muito bem, mas com a minha prática não. Muito obrigado Gomiero.

Comment: @Mueladavc De nada!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby(by=['Key']).sum()

    Value
Key 
a   19.6
b   16.0
c   16.8
```